# In how many ways the caps can be put into the box?

Tags: combinatorics

**

> There are $5$ distinct boxes $B_1...B_5$ and five distinct caps $C_1....C_5$. If
>   $B_1$ and $B_5$ have the caps $C_1$ and $C_5$ among themselves, in how many ways
>   can you arrange the caps among the $5$ boxes?

**

I have been a little confused while solving the above problem. According to me this should be the solution:

Since $B_1$ and $B_5$ contain $C_1$ and $C_5$ among themselves, there are in total $4$ ways:

1. $C_1$ and $C_5$ both in $B_1$
2. $C_1$ in $B_1$ and $C_5$ in $B_5$
3. $C_1$ in $B_5$ and $C_5$ in $B_1$
4. $C_1$ and $C_5$ both in $B_5$

Now assuming $C_1$ and $C_5$ have already contained in $B_1$ and $B_5$, we are left with:
$C_2$ $C_3$ $C_4$
The number of ways to place $C_2$ is by putting it in any of the 5 boxes, as there's no limitation to the number of balls a box can fit in.
Similarly for $C_3$ and $C_4$.

So according to me, the answer should be $4*5^3$

But in the key it's showing $375$. There's very much chance the key could be wrong but just wanted to confirm with you guys once.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct. First there are 4 ways to distribute $C_1$ and $C_5$ among $B_1$ and $B_5$ as the problem states.

The number of ways to put the remaining $n=3$ distinct objects into $k=5$ distinct boxes is $k^n = 5^3$.

The first part of the problem is independent the second part of the problem. so we can use the multiplication principle after calculating the number of ways to distribute the remaining caps.

By the multiplication principle the final answer is $4 * 5^3 = 500$

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: My guess is whoever made the answer key miscalculated the ways to distribute $C_1$ and $C_5$ incorrectly. Looks like the answer key is $3*5^3$, but there are $4$ ways to do this as you enumerated.

Comment: Oh yea! I see... I think the same. thanks anyways :-)